# Javascript global error handling via AJAX/PHP: limit logs to my own script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, error-handling

I have a script that detects Javascript errors on my website and sends them to my backend for reporting:

```
<script>
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error){

    msg   = msg || '';
    url   = url || '';
    line  = parseInt(line || 0);

    // Note that col & error are new to the HTML 5 spec and may not be supported in every browser.
    col   = parseInt(col || 0);
    error = error || '';

    try
    {
        // Ajax Request for IE 5.5+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari XHR object
        var x = new (this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        x.open('POST', '/log.php', 1);
        x.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        x.send('msg='+encodeURIComponent(msg)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&line='+line+'&col='+col+'&error='+encodeURIComponent(error));

        x.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( (x.readyState > 3) && (x.status > 0 && x.status < 400))
                window.console && console.log(x.responseText);
        };
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        window.console && console.log(e);
    }

    return true;
};
</script>
```

I have a server-side php script that will listen for Ajax request and writes a log file

```
<?php

if( $handle = fopen('log.txt', 'a') ) {

    $log = date('d/m/Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($_REQUEST['msg']) )
         $log .= 'msg:'.$_REQUEST['msg'].PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($_REQUEST['url']) )
         $log .= 'url:'.$_REQUEST['url'].PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($_REQUEST['line']) )
         $log .= 'line:'.$_REQUEST['line'].PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($_REQUEST['col']) )
         $log .= 'col:'.$_REQUEST['col'].PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($_REQUEST['error']) )
         $log .= 'error:'.$_REQUEST['error'].PHP_EOL;

    $log .= '---------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($handle, $log);

    fclose($handle);

    echo 1;

} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

if in a page rise a javascript exception, eg:

```
<script> call_undefined_function(); </script>
```

write in the log file...

```
25/10/2014 11:31:08
msg:ReferenceError: call_undefined_function is not defined
url:http://www.test.it/
line:46
col:1
error:ReferenceError: call_undefined_function is not defined
---------------------------------------------
```

**Everything works quite well!**

**But**, i find a lot of logs raised by plug-ins, toolbars, worms or browser extensions used by the users...

eg

```
24/10/2014 10:20:32
msg:Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame
url: http://ads.XXXXXX.net/?XXXXXX
line:0
col:0
error:Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame
---------------------------------------------
```

*Obviously this script is not my site and doing some research I found to be a worm of internet explorer*

my questions is: **How can I limit the logs to my own script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always check against the URL:

```
// If the script is not being loaded from my domain
if(url.indexOf('http://mydomain') == -1)
{
    // Allow the error to propagate normally
    return false;
}
```

This may not be effective however if some third party is injecting inline scripts as opposed to externally loaded ones.