# error handling from AJAX action page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I developed my web-application using PHP, AJAX, and jQuery. It went smoothly. 
Most of the requests made to the application are from AJAX; all insert, update, delete, and select

I already made some error handling for the pages in my application which are not by accessed via AJAX.

My problem is; in my application AJAX is used thousands of times. Now it will take a LOT of effort to add error handling to all of those endpoints.

My question is; is there a way that I can use some form of generic error handling in AJAX, or can I redirect from an AJAX action page to another page displaying an error (as that would also be fine)?

I'm 99% sure this is not possible, but I want some expert advice.

Comment: create ajax helper function
that will handle all your ajax call
from the ajax helper then you can create a error handling for your ajax request

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561231/javascript-global-error-handling-via-ajax-php-limit-logs-to-my-own-script

Comment: But I dont have error in ajax,

Suppose I have one action page indexAction and there is error in its insert query then how can I know

and notify user that some thing went wrong

Comment: in many case if we return some json or some id in ajax then we can predict but my all ajax call are only throwing request don't get any reply just throw insert parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have copied your code a thousend times, this is not very efficient ;-)

Do the following.

function CommunicateWithServer(settings){
// do the ajax thing

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: settings.async,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: settings.url + settings.method,
        data: settings.data,
    }).done(function (d) {
        // do a generic thing on done
        settings.done(d);
    }).fail(function(d) {
       // do a generic thing on fail here

        if (settings.fail) {
            settings.fail(d);
        } 

    }).always(function (d) {
        settings.always(d);
    });
```

}

and call this code everywhere you now use directly the jquery Ajax.
This way you can implement new generic features along the way of the program life.

To use this code:

Put this function in a js file that is used on every page, then instead of doing $.Ajax(), do:

```
hereYourSettings = {
   async:false,
   url : "yourUrl",
   method: "yourMethod",
   data: {dataIsCool:true},  // <== Put your data object here
   done: function(rawData){alert("yes!");},
   fail: function(rawData){alert("snap!");},
   always: function(rawData){alert("And I'ieII.., Will always love you!");},
}
```

CommunicateWithServer(hereYourSettings);

When you persist in keeping your old code:
use: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/missing.html" ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
  }
});
```

Comment: you mean to say Put this code in document.ready 
and track other ajax

Comment: indeed, that is a really good habit when you are using "external" stuff like jquery.

Comment: I got your function but How to use this I am confused What parameters goes in settingd ?

Comment: NOw I got you are asking me to replace this function with my thousands of AJAX calls .....:(

Comment: Indeed my friend ;-)  You should really do this, it is much better then fiddling arround and copying a thousand times the same code..

Comment: yes I can understand you , I am not actually using your function but show me one new path Thanks very much ,
I will post also my answer after getting succuss but believe Going in your direction with minimum effert :)

Comment: see the adjustment in my answer, hoping to help you.

Comment: You caught me right , I am going on exactly this way

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ajaxSetup in jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/). Using ajaxSetup, you can set defaults for all AJAX requests that your application makes. As an example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST', // All AJAX requests will be POST unless explicitly specified in the AJAX call,
    error: function() {
        // Your error handling for all AJAX calls.
    }
});
```

Now, if you make a call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/savedata/',
    data: somedata,
})
```

This will be a POST request, due to the defaults setup by `$.ajaxSetup`. However, if you make a request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/getdata/',
    error: function(){
         // Different error handling code
    }
});
```

This will be a GET request since you have overridden the defaults of `$.ajaxSetup` with different way of error handling.